# Reactjs component does not call componentWillMount method when route is matched

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to create an SPA using React. 
I have an `index.js` and `App.js, SidebarContentWrap.js, Sidebar.js, Content.js` components.

`index.js` has `BrowserRouter` and calls `App.js` Component.

`App.js` fetches data from API in `componentWillMount` method and then renders a dynamic route `<Route path={`/playlist/:slug`} component={SidebarContentWrap}/>`

According to my understanding whenever route will match, `componentWillMount` in `SidebarContentWrap` will be called and I will fetch data in it and then render that data. But it does not happen.

Here is some of my code.

```
/*App.js*/
class App extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            playLists: [],
            dataRoute: `${Config.apiUrl}playlists?per_page=3`
        }
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        fetch(this.state.dataRoute)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(playlists => this.setState((prevState, props) => {
                return { playLists : playlists.map( playlist => {
                            return { name: playlist.name, slug: playlist.slug}
                        }
                    )};
            }));
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <Header />
            <switch>
                {/*<Route path={`/playlist/:slug`} render={({match})=><SidebarContentWrap match={match} playLists={this.state.playLists}/>}/>*/}
                <Route path={`/playlist/:slug`} component={SidebarContentWrap}/>
            </switch>
            <Footer />
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

AND

```
/*SidebarContentWrap.js*/
class SidebarContentWrap extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        //FETCH DATA HERE EVERY TIME WHEN URL IS CHANGED
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="sidebar-content-wrap">
                <div className="wrap clearfix">
                    <main className="App-content">
                        {/*<Route path={`/playlist/:slug`} render={()=><Content/>}/>*/}
                        <Content />
                    </main>
                    <aside className="App-sidebar">
                        <div className="tabs">
                            {/*{this.props.playLists.map((playlist) =>*/}
                                {/*<NavLink key={playlist.slug} to={`/playlist/${playlist.slug}`}>{playlist.name}</NavLink>*/}
                            {/*)}*/}
                            <NavLink key="playlist-1" to="/playlist/playlist-1">Playlist 1</NavLink>
                            <NavLink key="playlist-2" to="/playlist/playlist-2">Playlist 2</NavLink>
                            <NavLink key="playlist-3" to="/playlist/playlist-3">Playlist 3</NavLink>
                        </div>
                        <div className="tabs-content">
                            {this.props.match.params.slug}
                            {/*<Route path={`/playlist/:slug`} render={()=><Sidebar/>}/>*/}
                            <Sidebar />
                        </div>
                    </aside>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SidebarContentWrap;
```

Comment: Does your `SidebarContentWrap` get rendered at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`componentWillMount` only get's called once when the component is first rendered. When your route changes, you aren't unmounting that component, so that's why `componentWillMount` never gets called again. What you want is to use `componentWillReceiveProps` instead. When you change the route, new router props will get passed to the component. So you should use `componentWillReceiveProps` to react to a url change.

You'll still want your fetch in `componentWillMount` for the very first time the component is rendered, but after that, the fetching should happen in `componentWillReceiveProps`.

```
class SidebarContentWrap extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        this.fetchData(this.props);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        this.fetchData(nextProps);
    }

    fetchData(props) {
        //FETCH DATA HERE EVERY TIME WHEN URL IS CHANGED
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="sidebar-content-wrap">
                <div className="wrap clearfix">
                    <main className="App-content">
                        {/*<Route path={`/playlist/:slug`} render={()=><Content/>}/>*/}
                        <Content />
                    </main>
                    <aside className="App-sidebar">
                        <div className="tabs">
                            {/*{this.props.playLists.map((playlist) =>*/}
                                {/*<NavLink key={playlist.slug} to={`/playlist/${playlist.slug}`}>{playlist.name}</NavLink>*/}
                            {/*)}*/}
                            <NavLink key="playlist-1" to="/playlist/playlist-1">Playlist 1</NavLink>
                            <NavLink key="playlist-2" to="/playlist/playlist-2">Playlist 2</NavLink>
                            <NavLink key="playlist-3" to="/playlist/playlist-3">Playlist 3</NavLink>
                        </div>
                        <div className="tabs-content">
                            {this.props.match.params.slug}
                            {/*<Route path={`/playlist/:slug`} render={()=><Sidebar/>}/>*/}
                            <Sidebar />
                        </div>
                    </aside>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SidebarContentWrap;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change the route with a Link, the component doesn't get remounted, it re-renders. You need to add the fetching logic to `componentWillReceiveProps`

```
class SidebarContentWrap extends Component {
  //...
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        //fetch
  }
}
```